# android inapp query product list returns null

Tags: android, in-app-billing, billing

I'm using inapp billing servcie ver 3.

APK upload to Google Play Console's Alpha Test and Make Inapp Products

and set my gmail adress to testing inapp purchase.

I was test many in app product. That works Great!

I'm doing well!!!!!!

However, Today i got problems.

request get available product list returns null...

inappbilling service setup done,
product id is correct.

There is no error on request and response.

but product list is null

here is my code

```
Bundle querySkus = new Bundle();
        querySkus.putStringArrayList(GET_SKU_DETAILS_ITEM_LIST, skuList);
        Bundle skuDetails = mService.getSkuDetails(3, mContext.getPackageName(),
                itemType, querySkus);

ArrayList<String> responseList = skuDetails.getStringArrayList("DETAILS_LIST");
```

responseList is null

wtf...

What is it?

Help me please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not the only one. I have seen the same issue from yesterday.
Help, google, help :)

Comment: me too, fixed... i don't understand.